# How should I mock state in a functional stateful component with state hooks when testing?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

If I have a stateful functional component that uses state hooks, how can I manipulate the state from outside the component? I want to be able change the state in my tests so that I can test how the dom changes.

I want to be able to change the value of something like this from outside of the component:

`const [sent, setSent] = useState(false);`

Answer (score 0):

I would not test the internal state of the component but rather what this state might represent. The usage of the state is an implementation detail and you should test if the specification is implemented correctly and not how it is implemented.

In your case I would use the following approach:

1. Call the functionality that should set the sent state (button click,
   form submit)
2. Test if the sent status is handled correctly in your
   component (a success message is shown?)

Testing loading states of api calls can be achieved with mocks. If you don't use some fancy library but just do normal `await apiCall()` then you can use following approach:

1. Mock your api call (you probably already doing it)
2. Return a `Promise()` from the mock that will not be resolved

Example with enzyme:

```
import { apiCall } from '../api';
jest.mock('../api');
// ...

it('Contains a <Loading /> on loading', () => {
  // The promise won't be resolved so the loading state will persist
  apiCall.mockReturnValue(new Promise(() => null));

  // await act... and wrapper.update() might not be needed 
  // depending on your implementation
  await act(async () => {
    wrapper.find(SubmitButton).simulate('click');
  });
  wrapper.update();

  expect(wrapper.find(Loading)).toHaveLength(1);
});
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking initially, but what about intermediate states? For example, how can I test that a spinner shows when the button is clicked and disappears when the button handler is finished?

Comment: I have added an example of what approach we are using in the company